# How to connect spinner items with data

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I'm trying to build an Android app for car service. I put a spinner with items such as "oil change" etc. Is it possible to do this kind of activity that when I choose something from the spinner, the application shows me how many kilometers and time it is until the next oil change? Should I use SQLite with int and time for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. Set a listener using [`setOnItemClickListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) and trigger whatever code you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses a spinner and selecting it shows the distance to the next item change and the current odometer reading. It's very basic and rather than using the date/time of service uses the odometer reading and (kilometers).

> Should I use SQLite with int and time for this?

- You would probably want two intervals the distance and the time as servicing is often on a whichever comes first (the distance travelled or the time since the lasts service) **the examples only assumes distance**.

It is based upon 3 tables one for the **cars**, one for the **service_items** (oil filter change etc) and then a mapping/reference table (**intervals**). This has one row for each car/service item each row includes the referenced car and the referenced service_item, the odometer reading when the item was last serviced and the service interval.

It has a spinner that allows you to select the service item and selecting a service item displays how long to the next service for that item.

The database helper, **DBHelper.java** (subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper class) is :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "service";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBITEM = "service_item";
    public static final String TBCAR = "car";
    public static final String TBINTERVAL = "interval";

    public static final String COL_TBITEMS_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_TBITEMS_NAME = "item_name";
    static final String crt_items_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TBITEM + "(" +
            COL_TBITEMS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_TBITEMS_NAME + " TEXT " +
            ")";

    public static final String COL_TBCAR_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_TBCAR_OWNERNAME = "owner_name";
    public static final String COL_TBCAR_ODOMETER = "odometer";
    static final String crt_car_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TBCAR + "(" +
            COL_TBCAR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_TBCAR_OWNERNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COL_TBCAR_ODOMETER + " INTEGER " +
            ")";

    public static final String COL_TBINTERVAL_ITEMREF = "item_id_reference";
    public static final String COL_TBINTERVAL_CARREF = "car_id_reference";
    public static final String COL_TBINTERVAL_INTERVAL = "item_interval";
    public static final String COL_TBINTERVAL_LASTDONE = "item_last_done";
    static final String crt_intervals_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TBINTERVAL + "(" +
            COL_TBINTERVAL_ITEMREF + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TBITEM + "(" + COL_TBITEMS_ID + ")," +
            COL_TBINTERVAL_CARREF + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TBCAR + "(" + COL_TBCAR_ID + ")," +
            COL_TBINTERVAL_INTERVAL + " INTEGER, " +
            COL_TBINTERVAL_LASTDONE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 " +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crt_items_sql);
        db.execSQL(crt_car_sql);
        db.execSQL(crt_intervals_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addCar(String name, long odometer) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TBCAR_OWNERNAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_TBCAR_ODOMETER,odometer);
        return mDB.insert(TBCAR,null,cv);
    }

    public long addItem(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TBITEMS_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(TBITEM,null,cv);
    }

    public long addInterval(long item_id, long car_id, long interval, long last_done) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TBINTERVAL_ITEMREF, item_id);
        cv.put(COL_TBINTERVAL_CARREF, car_id);
        cv.put(COL_TBINTERVAL_INTERVAL,interval);
        cv.put(COL_TBINTERVAL_LASTDONE,last_done);
        return mDB.insert(TBINTERVAL,null,cv);
    }


    public long getCarOdometer(long car_id) {
        long rv = -1;
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBCAR,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TBCAR_ODOMETER));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public long getNextDueForItem(long car_id, long item_id) {
        long rv = -1;
        long odometer = getCarOdometer(car_id);
        long last_done = 0;
        long interval = 0;
        String whereclause = COL_TBINTERVAL_ITEMREF + "=? AND " + COL_TBINTERVAL_CARREF + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(item_id),String.valueOf(car_id)};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBINTERVAL,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            last_done = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TBINTERVAL_LASTDONE));
            interval = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_TBINTERVAL_INTERVAL));
            long dueat = last_done + interval;
            rv = dueat - odometer;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

The Activity **MainActivity.java** is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner mSpinner;
    TextView mSpinner_selection;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mSA;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList("Change Oil","Change Oil Filter","Change Air Filter","Change Spark Plugs")
    );
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    long mCurrentCar = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSpinner = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mSpinner_selection = this.findViewById(R.id.selected_spinner);
        mSpinner_selection.setText("Nothing selected as yet"); //<<<< will likely not be seen

        // Instaiate the Database Helper (will create the Database and tables when first run)
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        addSomeData();
        handleSpinner();
    }

    // Setup the Spinner and the Item Select Listener
    private void handleSpinner() {
        if (mSA == null) {
            mSA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(mSA);
            mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    //<<<<<<<<<< NOTE not the best way as assumes a direct map
                    // from the list to the service_item.
                    long duein = mDBHlpr.getNextDueForItem(mCurrentCar,(long)i + 1);
                    long odometer = mDBHlpr.getCarOdometer(mCurrentCar);
                    String text_to_show =
                            "You are due to " + mSA.getItem(i) + " in " + String.valueOf(duein) +
                                    "Your Odometer reads " + String.valueOf(odometer);
                    mSpinner_selection.setText(text_to_show);
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Add some data, a car and the service items based upon the ArrayList of items
    // noting that for display purposes the interval increase per service_item
    private void addSomeData() {
        long thiscar = mDBHlpr.addCar("My Car",1123);
        long interval = 10000;
        for (String s: items) {
            long thisitem = mDBHlpr.addItem(s);
            mDBHlpr.addInterval(thisitem,thiscar,interval,0);
            interval = interval + 500;
        }
    }
}
```

The layout for the MainActivity is **activity_main.xml** is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

- **Note** this is just a demo, to show how a spinner can be used.
- When first run it will show :-

[image]

- Selecting Change Oil Filter will show :-

[image]

- 10500 because 500 is progressively added to the service interval in the addSomeData method in MainActivity (just to show different data).